# Error: constant value required while compiling with avr-as in linux

Tags: microcontroller, avr, assembly, error

Im trying to compile the following simple assembly program but there is a problem with the compiler that i cannot find its reason and fix it.

So here is the code :

```
  1 #define __SFR_OFFSET 0 
  2 #include <avr/io.h> 
  3 
  4 
  5 rjmp Init 
  6 
  7 .global Init 
  8 
  9 Init:   sbi _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB),5 
 10         rjmp In
```

and when im going to compile it with
`avr-as -c -mmcu=atmega168a -o ledON.o ledON.s`

i am getting this error:

```
ledON.s: Assembler messages:  
ledON.s:9: Error: constant value required
ledON.s:9: Error: `,' required  
ledON.s:9: Error: constant value required
ledON.s:9: Error: garbage at end of line
```

I also change a little bit the code as you can see above but there is still an error

```
  1 ;#define _SFR_OFFSET 0 
  2 #include <avr/io.h> 
  3 
  4 rjmp Init
  5 
  6 .global Init
  7 
  8 Init:   sbi PORTB,0x05
  9         rjmp Init
```

> ledON.s: Assembler messages:
>
> ledON.s:8: Error: constant value required

Any ideas?

Comment: What version `avr-as` are you using, mine doesn't support the `-c` flag, what does it do?

Comment: Even without `-c` flag im getting the same error :s

Comment: Clearly the include files are not processed at all, now only to figure out how why that is.

Comment: And where to look to determine that ? Can you give me some hint ?

Comment: I've been experimenting a bit and clearly the include files are not processed. It has to do with the fact that as doesn't call the C-preprocessor, but I don't know how to force the files being processed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to assemble without error messages.

The error messages you see are caused by the fact that `avr-as` does *not* invoke the C-preprocessor and therefore the `#include` lines are read as regular comments.

Create a file `ledON.S` and notice the CAPITAL `S` in the filename. The capital `S` indicates that the C-preprocessor must be invoked first. Create the file with the following content:

```
#include <avr/io.h> 

init:   sbi     _SFR_IO_ADDR(DDRB),0x05         ; Configure port B pin 5 as output
        ret

.global main

main:
        call init

loop:
        sbi     _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB),0x05        ; Toggle output pin HIGH
        cbi     _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTB),0x05        ; Toggle output pin LOW
        rjmp loop
```

The `main` part is required in the source code, this is where usually the main program is located. If you remove it, no real code is executed ever and thus the compiler will complain about that. Code in a routine called `init` should be explicitly called from `main`. Although the pin toggles, in practice this will be too fast to see with the bare eye. If you check with an oscilloscope you'll see a square wave (I estimate at 25% duty cycle).

Then assemble the source code with:

```
avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega168a ledON.S -o ledON.o
```

Again `avr-gcc` is required to invoke the C-preprocessor.

To check the result of the assembled program run the following command:

```
avr-objdump -C -d ./ledON.o
```

And the resulting disassembly listing looks like this:

```
./ledON.o:     file format elf32-avr


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <__vectors>:
   0:   0c 94 34 00     jmp     0x68    ; 0x68 <__ctors_end>
   4:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
   8:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
   c:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  10:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  14:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  18:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  1c:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  20:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  24:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  28:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  2c:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  30:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  34:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  38:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  3c:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  40:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  44:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  48:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  4c:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  50:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  54:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  58:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  5c:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  60:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>
  64:   0c 94 3e 00     jmp     0x7c    ; 0x7c <__bad_interrupt>

00000068 <__ctors_end>:
  68:   11 24           eor     r1, r1
  6a:   1f be           out     0x3f, r1        ; 63
  6c:   cf ef           ldi     r28, 0xFF       ; 255
  6e:   d4 e0           ldi     r29, 0x04       ; 4
  70:   de bf           out     0x3e, r29       ; 62
  72:   cd bf           out     0x3d, r28       ; 61
  74:   0e 94 42 00     call    0x84    ; 0x84 <main>
  78:   0c 94 47 00     jmp     0x8e    ; 0x8e <_exit>

0000007c <__bad_interrupt>:
  7c:   0c 94 00 00     jmp     0       ; 0x0 <__vectors>

00000080 <init>:
  80:   25 9a           sbi     0x04, 5 ; 4
  82:   08 95           ret

00000084 <main>:
  84:   0e 94 40 00     call    0x80    ; 0x80 <init>

00000088 <loop>:
  88:   2d 9a           sbi     0x05, 5 ; 5
  8a:   2d 98           cbi     0x05, 5 ; 5
  8c:   fd cf           rjmp    .-6             ; 0x88 <loop>

0000008e <_exit>:
  8e:   f8 94           cli

00000090 <__stop_program>:
  90:   ff cf           rjmp    .-2             ; 0x90 <__stop_program>
```

> **INTERMEZZO**
>
> You'll notice the assembler will automatically initialize the stack pointer
>   and status register in `__ctors_end`.
>   Also it will automatically add a `rjmp` at the end of the code.
>   Default behaviour of a program assembled by gcc-avr when it ends is:
>
> - turn off interrupts (`_exit`, `cli`)
> - infinite empty loop that does nothing (`__stop_program`, `rjmp .-2`)

Comment: Yes. I have already try the .S but once again it returns me an error and it doesn't create the object file. `ledON.S: Assembler messages:
ledON.S:8: Error: number must be positive and less than 32` such errors i believe that means that the I/O register is not editable.

Comment: Copy the exact source as in my answer and work from there. My proposed source builds on my system, otherwise I couldn't show you the disassembly listing.

Comment: OK. the object file now created but why all these happens ? I cannot understand. Also in your code the rjmp to main will never be executed because there is init's infinity loop above. Btw i cannot upvote because i am new user and i don't have reputation.

Comment: Fair enough, I removed the last `rjmp`. The `main` label is a required part of the program, if you remove it you get receive an error message. Normally that is the where the main program is located.

Comment: @F.N I updated the answer to reflect a somewhat useful proof of concept.

Comment: Yes i saw it. I compiled it , linked it and tested it . Led worked. Thank you very much. So the problem is in the assembler but do you think that there is a way to fix it or not ?

Comment: According to the documentation, this is the way it works. You want the C-preprocessor invoked, then call gcc.

Comment: @F.N http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/assembler.html

Comment: but this guy here ? how he made it work with avr-as? [avr-as](http://nerdathome.blogspot.gr/2008/04/avr-as-usage-tutorial.html)

Comment: @F.N Don't know. Things have chaged since 'April 8, 2008' though. The toolchain has entirely different major versions (the first digit of the version number). Under water `avr-gcc` calls `avr-as` for you.

Comment: @F.N Also notice that that example doesn't call for inclusion of the C header files.

Comment: Yes i got it. Anyway. I ll try some other things and if i find something i ll inform you :) Thank you very much once again.